# How to implement the Microsoft Speaker Recognition / Verification API in Python?

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, voice-recognition

I would like to implement the Speaker Recognition API from Microsoft's Cognitive Services for a Speaker Verification project. I already have a Speaker Recognition API key. I got the sample Python code directly from the documentation (on the bottom of the documentation):

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/563309b7778daf06340c9652

```
    ########### Python 3.2 #############
    import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

    headers = {
        # Request headers
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{subscription key}',
    }

    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    })

    try:
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
        conn.request("POST", "/spid/v1.0/verificationProfiles?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read()
        print(data)
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

    ####################################
```

This is the code sample for the first step, create and save a voice profile.

To conduct Speaker Verification, we need to do 3 steps:
1) Create Profile
2) Create Enrollment
3) Verification

I'm stuck already at the first step now. This is my first time working with APIs in general, so I'm not really sure what parts of the Python code I have to change. I know that I need do insert my API key in **'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'** but other than that, what else? For example, if I add my API key in that specific field and let the code run, I received this error message.

```
b'{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"locale is not specified"}}'
```

Where do I need to insert the locale ("en-us") for example? It is not really clear to me from the documentation what I need to edit. If you can guide me what I need to insert/add in my API calls I would be very thankful.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Speaker Recognition profile, it has to be linked with a locale, and you specify this locale in the request body. The body should be a JSON object like the following one:

```
{
  "locale":"en-us",
}
```

For the sample to work, you need to replace "{body}" with the actual body value like this:

```
conn.request("POST", "/spid/v1.0/verificationProfiles?%s" % params, "{\"locale\":\"en-US\"}", headers)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! It worked and I also successfully implemented the enrollment and verification steps. The main point is to replace the **"{body}"** in each step with the required information.